# How do I clear the screen in a terminal using Perl?

Tags: perl, terminal, screen

I would like to clear the screen in a terminal/console using Perl. How can I do that?

---

This is a question from the [official perlfaq](http://faq.perl.org). We're [importing the perlfaq to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/can-we-import-the-perlfaq-into-stackoverflow).

Answer (score 13):

This is the [offical FAQ answer](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_clear_the_s) minus any subsequent edits.

To clear the screen, you just have to print the special sequence that tells the terminal to clear the screen. Once you have that sequence, output it when you want to clear the screen.

You can use the [Term::ANSIScreen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::ANSIScreen) module to get the special sequence. Import the `cls` function (or the `:screen` tag):

```
use Term::ANSIScreen qw(cls);
my $clear_screen = cls();

print $clear_screen;
```

The [Term::Cap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::Cap) module can also get the special sequence if you want to deal with the low-level details of terminal control. The Tputs method returns the string for the given capability:

```
use Term::Cap;

$terminal = Term::Cap->Tgetent( { OSPEED => 9600 } );
$clear_string = $terminal->Tputs('cl');

print $clear_screen;
```

On Windows, you can use the [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::Console) module. After creating an object for the output filehandle you want to affect, call the `Cls` method:

```
Win32::Console;

$OUT = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
my $clear_string = $OUT->Cls;

print $clear_screen;
```

If you have a command-line program that does the job, you can call it in backticks to capture whatever it outputs so you can use it later:

```
$clear_string = `clear`;

print $clear_string;
```

Comment: You saved the best for last! Capturing the output of the "clear" command line for later repeated consumption is a great trick, and did the trick.

Comment: There is a small bug in the answer. Variable `$clear_string` gets the value, but when printing the variable with slightly different name is used `$clear_screen`.

Answer (score 9):

The shortest OS-independent (and not needing additional modules installations) method that worked for me was found in the [Perl Monks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=18774) (that page also contains some other variations of clearing the screen):

```
system $^O eq 'MSWin32' ? 'cls' : 'clear';
```

Answer (score 6):

Linux Users use the following command:

```
system 'clear';
```